# Error accesing ASP.net MVC Application under Umbraco Application IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco7

I am using Umbraco 7.2.4 Application in our Project, I have another application which should run under Umbraco Site. Like as Below:

Umbraco Root URL: SampleUmbraco.com

Child Application : SampleUmbraco.com/MyApplication

I create a sub application under the Root Umbraco Application in IIS, and I added my Application URL to “umbracoReservedPaths”: “~/myApplication”.

But still my child application “SampleUmbraco.com/MyApplication” is still not running.

Do I need to change any other configuration settings?

Can any one one Help me in this issue?

Comment: Have you done anything to prevent the child application from inheriting the  Umbraco web.config settings?

Comment: how had you mapped domains of application in backend?

Comment: I didnt done any changes to web.config. to prevent the child application. and i added child application to "umbracoReservedPaths" as below:

Comment: <addkey="umbracoReservedUrls"value="~/config/splashes/booting.aspx,~/install/default.aspx,~/config/splashes/noNodes.aspx,~/VSEnterpriseHelper.axd,~/SampleApplication/" />

<addkey="umbracoReservedPaths"value="~/umbraco,~/install,~/SampleApplication/" />

Comment: In the web.config, is there a location element? Which modules are specified in the `system.webServer` element?

Also, do you get any errors when you navigate to the child application?

Comment: please refer https://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/running-multiple-websites-on-one-umbraco-installation before for creating multiple sites in one umbraco. you need to map the domain name for each site.

Answer (score 0):

Is myApplication not running at all, or does it give an error? We have previously had to add a location element around system.web and system.webServer in the web.config to make "sub" applications work. Like this:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
  <system.web>
    ..
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    ..
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

But our sub applications were up, they "just" threw different YSOD errors.